# Erro na criação de chave estrangeria MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, script, chave-primária, chave-estrangeira

Estou com o seguinte erro:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `bravo`.`tb_gerenciador` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

segue o script:

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Wed Apr 26 12:35:57 2017
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Bravo
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Bravo
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Bravo` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `Bravo` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Bravo`.`fornecedor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bravo`.`tb_fornecedor` (
  `idFornecedor` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomeFornecedor` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `cnpjFornecedor` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `contatoFornecedor` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idFornecedor`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `cnpjFornecedor_UNIQUE` (`cnpjFornecedor` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 18
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bravo`.`tb_caminhao` (
  `idCaminhao` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `placaCaminhao` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `modeloCaminhao` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `pesoFinalCaminhao` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `pesoInicialCaminhao` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCaminhao`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `placa_UNIQUE` (`placaCaminhao` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 18
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bravo`.`tb_motorista` (
  `idMotorista` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomeMotorista` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cnhMotorista` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMotorista`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 18
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bravo`.`tb_gerenciador` (
  `idGerenciador` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gerenciador_nomeFornecedor` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `gerenciador_placaCaminhao` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `gerenciador_nomeMotorista` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `gerenciador_cnhMotorista` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idGerenciador`), 
  CONSTRAINT fk_gerenciador_nomeFornecedorr  FOREIGN KEY (`gerenciador_nomeFornecedor`) REFERENCES `tb_fornecedor` (`nomeFornecedor`),
  CONSTRAINT fk_gerenciador_placaCaminhao  FOREIGN KEY (`gerenciador_placaCaminhao`) REFERENCES `tb_caminhao` (`placaCaminhao`),
  CONSTRAINT fk_gerenciador_nomeMotorista FOREIGN KEY (`gerenciador_nomeMotorista`) REFERENCES `tb_motorista` (`nomeMotorista`),
  CONSTRAINT fk_gerenciador_cnhMotorista  FOREIGN KEY (`gerenciador_cnhMotorista`) REFERENCES `tb_motorista` (`cnhMotorista`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 18
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Alguem pode me ajudar??

Comment: A chave estrangeira precisa identificar univocamente uma linha da tabela destino. Utilize o campo chave primária da tabela destino como chave estrangeira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente a solução é essa:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Bravo` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;

USE `Bravo` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bravo`.`tb_fornecedor` (
  `idFornecedor` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomeFornecedor` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `cnpjFornecedor` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `contatoFornecedor` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idFornecedor`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `cnpjFornecedor_UNIQUE` (`cnpjFornecedor` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 18
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bravo`.`tb_caminhao` (
  `idCaminhao` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `placaCaminhao` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `modeloCaminhao` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `pesoFinalCaminhao` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `pesoInicialCaminhao` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCaminhao`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `placa_UNIQUE` (`placaCaminhao` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 18
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bravo`.`tb_motorista` (
  `idMotorista` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomeMotorista` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cnhMotorista` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMotorista`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 18
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Bravo`.`tb_gerenciador` (
  `idGerenciador` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gerenciador_idFornecedor` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `gerenciador_idCaminhao` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `gerenciador_idMotorista` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idGerenciador`), 
  CONSTRAINT fk_gerenciador_idFornecedor  
    FOREIGN KEY (`gerenciador_idFornecedor`) 
      REFERENCES `tb_fornecedor` (`idFornecedor`),
  CONSTRAINT fk_gerenciador_idCaminhao  
    FOREIGN KEY (`gerenciador_idCaminhao`) 
      REFERENCES `tb_caminhao` (`idCaminhao`),
  CONSTRAINT fk_gerenciador_idMotorista 
    FOREIGN KEY (`gerenciador_idMotorista`) 
      REFERENCES `tb_motorista` (`idMotorista`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 18
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Porque você relaciona chave estrangeira com a chave primária sendo essa do mesmo tipo, ou seja, se fez a tabela `tb_gerenciador` totalmente equivocada com os nomes dos campos que você pode recuperar com SQL facilmente.